# Casting subclass to superclass and calling a function that both classes have

Tags: java, casting

```
public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived04 b = new Derived04();
        Base04 a = (Base04)b;
        System.out.println(a.i);
        System.out.println(a.f());
    }
}

class Base04 {
    int i=1;
    public int f() {return i;}
}
class Derived04 extends Base04 {
    int i = 2; 
    public int f(){return -i;}
}
```

Both classes include the f() method so when I cast d onto a which method does it go to when I call a.f()?  I thinking since a is declared as Base04 type when you do a.i it gives 1 but then why does it use the method from the subclass?

Comment: You should (re)read the section about method overriding in your Java learning guide.

Comment: After looking at your question, I think that the interesting point isn't why it calls the method from the implemented class, which is what it is expected to do I think, but why it's printing `1` in `System.out.println(a.i)`. I think you should append the execution output to your question and ask about this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point is about implementing and casting. so when you create a `Derived04` then you have implemented a `Derived04` class, not its parents `Base04` so even if you cast it like that it will run the implemented method not the casting method unless there is a different between `f()` in both classes. and that's not our case.

Comment: What do you mean by difference between `f()`?  As in if `Derived04` had `f(int x)` and `Base04` has `f()`? ie difference in parameter or such?

Comment: for example if you change one of those ```f()``` to ```f(int x)``` then those two come apart and will be used  in different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

> why does it use the method from the subclass?

You create an object of `Derived04` class you just cast it to the type `Base04`. It is still `Derived04` implementation.