# Java field inheritance and upcasting weird behaviour

Tags: java, inheritance, upcasting

This question is inspired by [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421158/casting-subclass-to-superclass-and-calling-a-function-that-both-classes-have) I stumbled upon.

Given the following code:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived b = new Derived();
        Base a = b;

        System.out.println("b.i -> " + b.i);
        System.out.println("a.i -> " + a.i);
        System.out.println("b.getI() -> " + b.getI());
        System.out.println("a.getI() -> " + a.getI());
    }
}

class Base {
    int i = 1;

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    int i = 2;

    public int getI() {
        return -i;
    }
}

// Output:
// b.i -> 2
// a.i -> 1
// b.getI() -> -2
// a.getI() -> -2
```

Could someone explain why `a.i` is returning `1`? Shouldn't it be accessing `i` field in `Derived` class?

In addition, when debugging the code, I can see something like this:

[image: Debug screenshot]

There you can see that `Derived` class is storing a reference to `Base.i`.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't `Base.i` be inherited and overwritten by `Derived.i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've came across the feature of Java called variable Hiding. 
The field "i" in `Derived` hides the field "i" in class `Base`.

Unlike methods, the fields cannot be overridden in java, hence the behavior.

I've found a very in-depth [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java) on this topic that you might consider useful

Answer (score 1):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41379556/3605497 there is no field polymorphism in Java. This means that the field in the subclass is simply ***hiding*** the field in the superclass, and not overloading it.

Answer (score 1):

After some deeper googling, I eventually found the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414990/if-you-overwrite-a-field-in-a-subclass-of-a-class-the-subclass-has-two-fields-w).

The point is that member variables cannot be overridden like methods, they are just hidden, and upcasting allows to access the hidden method in the base class.